# Wrapping SQL query in parentheses causes syntax error

Tags: mysql

The following query works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `number`
   FROM `employee`
   WHERE `number` IN
            (SELECT `department_manager`
             FROM `department`)
   UNION
     (SELECT DISTINCT `manager`
      FROM `employee`
      WHERE `manager` IS NOT NULL)
```

But as soon as I wrap the query with parentheses it doesn't work anymore:

```
 (SELECT DISTINCT `number`
   FROM `employee`
   WHERE `number` IN
            (SELECT `department_manager`
             FROM `department`)
   UNION
     (SELECT DISTINCT `manager`
      FROM `employee`
      WHERE `manager` IS NOT NULL))
```

Causing syntax error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION
```

Wrapping other select queries in parentheses doesn't cause problems, this works for example:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT number FROM johnson.employee);
```

What is the difference between these?

Comment: The parentheses around the second select in the first query are already useless and not needed.

Comment: So don't wrap it in parentheses?

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff Wouldn't it be more fun if I actually knew why?

Comment: Aside from just saying that's the way MYSQL's rules are set I don't have an explanation.  I do know that if you remove all the parentheses as @a_horse_with_no_name states, the query works just fine.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9ba7/3

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff I have an example of working query wrapped in brackets, could you explain the difference of why that works but not my original?

Comment: I can't explain the difference but I did find out that it will work with your brackets if you put a `SELECT * FROM` and then a table alias around the query like here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9ba7/14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the way MySQL implemented its SQL grammar.

A `<query>` can be:

```
SELECT ... [ UNION <query>]
```

or

```
( SELECT ... ) [ UNION <query> ]
```

But apparently not

```
( SELECT ... UNION <query> )
```

Read `sql/sql_yacc.yy` in the MySQL source code if you want the details.

As a workaround, you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... UNION SELECT ... ) AS t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses around queries are subqueries -- think of this almost like a subroutine, where the inner query is executed first, then its result is evaluated in the context of the outer query.  In your second example, you are defining a subquery where no outer query exists, hence a syntax error.

You might be able to transform the second example into valid sql simply by putting a `SELECT` before the first parenthesis and 'FROM DUMMY' after the closing parenthesis; try it.

Comment: I have several other queries where wrapping in brackets doesn't cause any problems. Here is one:

    `(SELECT DISTINCT number FROM johnson.employee)`

What is the difference here?